# Select and echo rows from 1 - 7

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have been trying to understand the use of selecting and echo only a limited row numbers from a table but I don't understand how to implemented it in the code so I hope somebody can help

I have this code where I first of want to echo in the loop only where the column id is 1-7 (this is also row 1-7) how can I do this
I understand that this should be the way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) NUM,
* FROM bangpakong
) 
WHERE NUM >0 AND NUM <7
```

But the above just give me a syntax error when I use that in the code the following is the code working without only picking the rows between 1-7

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bangpakong";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<div class='boks'>";
    echo "<div id='courseC'>";
echo "<img src='http://pattayasports.org/calendar/wp-
content/uploads/2017/11/Bangpakong-2.jpg' />";
echo "<p class='pleft'>Contact: 038 500 500 - 081 761 4874</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='Crate'>";



    echo "<div class='Cheader'>";
        echo "<div>";

            echo "<div>Day</div>";
            echo "<div>PSC GF</div>";
            echo "<div>Visitor GF</div>";
            echo "<div>Cart</div>";
            echo "<div>Caddy</div>";


        echo "</div>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div>";

            echo "<div>" . $row['day'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div>" . $row['cf'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div>" . $row['viscf'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div>" . $row['cart'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div>" . $row['caddy'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div>" . $row['note'] . "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Are you using the [MySQL/8 preview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are using a very new version of MySQL which supports the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, your query would not run on MySQL.  But if you want the first 7 records from your table ordered by the `ID` column, we can use `LIMIT` to the same effect:

```
SELECT *
FROM bangpakong
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for you explanation of why the row_number won't work on the server, and thanks for the solution too